# avformat_open_input returns -2 (Android)

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm using [this](https://github.com/xorange/Android-Video-Player-FFmpeg-and-Bitmap) FFMPEG port for Android.
My Goal is to read RTSP stream eventually.

I can open a stream from a local file (located at *"/storage/emulated/0/bunny.mp4"*) ,
using ***avformat_open_input*** function.

However when I try to open the same file from remote location like ***"http_://192.168.1.183/bunny.mp4***" , it returns error **-2** .

The whole cpp code is [here](http://pastie.org/8364052).

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have INTERNET permission in your manifest.

Also check that you are building ffmpeg with tcp and rtsp protocol enabled. And  codecs enabled, too. I believe FFMPEG's `configure` prints this info when building and also it's in the build log.

Also, there's a FFMPEG function to print error message by code, don't remember the name though. So you can call it and see what -2 error means.

This here project has FFMPEG configured correctly https://github.com/dannoy/dolphin-player look in the `p` folder

Comment: I did add INTERNET permission. I guess the problem is that networking and/or protocols are disabled.Regarding Dolphin Player  , can't compile it :(

Comment: It compiles cleanly under Ubuntu

Comment: I've used compiled libffmpeg.so file from DolphinPlayer in my project , and I no longer get an error on avformat_open_input :) So I guess there WAS a problem in networking and/or protocols. I'll accept your answer since it helped me to solve my issue.